# Problem solving first order ODE's with DSolve

Tags: differential-equations, symbolic

The issue I am facing is the following. I am trying to solve a system of two coupled first order ODE's with DSolve:

```
eqns = {A*f'[x] == -x*f[x]/2 + B*g[x], A*g'[x] == x*g[x]/2 + B*f[x]};
DSolve[eqns, {f[x], g[x]}, x]
```

As output this just gives the same command, which from what I gather means that DSolve cannot solve it.

But if I just explicitly substitute the equations into one another, then suddenly it can be solved:

```
fun = f[x] /. Solve[A*g'[x] == x*g[x]/2 + B*f[x], f[x]];
dfun = D[fun, x];
DSolve[A*f'[x] == -x*f[x]/2 + B*g[x] /. {f[x] -> fun, f'[x] -> dfun}, 
 g[x], x]
```

This gives

```
{{g[x] -> 
   C[2] ParabolicCylinderD[B^2/A, (I x)/Sqrt[A]] + 
    C[1] ParabolicCylinderD[(-A - B^2)/A, x/Sqrt[A]]}}
```

This makes me think that I'm simply doing something wrong in the first line, which is probably some silly notation mistake. If someone would be able to help me out, I'd be very thankful.

Comment: Nothing wrong with what you did; only that `DSolve[]` is not sufficiently smart to recognize that the problem can be manipulated to something solvable.

Comment: Hm, I see. Well, that's okay I suppose! Thank you. What does one do with the question in this case? I'll look around in the meta part of the site a bit to figure that out, but perhaps it comes up more often.

Comment: You could try reporting this example to Wolfram support; then maybe a future version of `DSolve[]` will be smarter than the current version. ;)

Comment: I tried with **Mathematica 12.0** and can't solve :(